# Admob openx integration

Tags: integration, admob, openx

We are using openx to serve ads. However there are times when we don't have enough Ads and would like to serve admob Ads. Is there an openx - admob integration that allows us to setup a banner or zone that will just call out to admob?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look at http://www.adwhirl.com/     (ADWhirl) - this is an open source product which allows you to serve up admod adverts, together with a bunsh of other ad-type services, as well as "house ads" which are your own ads - maybe that is worth a look ?